# Number Format Exception in Program

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that involves taking a size of an array, and strings that fit in to that array, then converting those strings in to ascii integers and seeing which one is greater.
I am getting these errors and am unsure of what to do:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "74111104110"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
at MinMax.minMax(MinMax.java:27)
at MinMax.main(MinMax.java:14)
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
public class MinMax {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the size of the Array");
    int sizeN = in.nextInt();

    ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(sizeN);
    for(int i =0; i < sizeN; i++){
        System.out.println("What strings would you like to evaluate?");
        String str = in.next();
        myArrayList.add(str);
    }
    minMax(sizeN, myArrayList);
}
public static void minMax(int sizeN, ArrayList<String> N){
    int[] sumArrayList = new int[sizeN];
    String stringInt = "";
    int temp = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 99999;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeN; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<N.get(i).length(); j++){
            temp = (int) N.get(i).charAt(j);
            stringInt += String.valueOf(temp);
        }
        sumArrayList[i] = Integer.valueOf(stringInt);

    }
    for (int j : sumArrayList) {
        if (j > max) {
            max = j;
        }
        if (j < min) {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("["+min+","+max+"]");
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's because 74111104110 is out of range of an Integer capacity.
Integer goes from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

You need to cast your String in Long

```
sumArrayList[I] = Long.parseLong(stringInt);
```

Also you need to modify your array and all your variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
   74111104110
```

is greater than 2^32 (an integer is represented by 4 byte(4byte * 8bit = 32bit)). When you need an integer greater than it, use long (64 bit)